# How to create an array based on user text input?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a text field named "number of rooms" with with + and - button on either side to set the value(max is 5).If the user selects 3 clicking the + or - button I want the array a = {1,2,3} and so on

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Why would you want an array of consecutive numbers?

Answer (score -1):

Declare a global Variable let suppose i=0
Now on every + click increase its value by 1 and on every - click decrease the value by 1 now finally loop

```
for(x=1;x<=i;x++)
{
put x value in array here
}
```

cheers  :)